# How can I compare two pandas dataframes and return an index mapping them to each other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, df1, and df2.  These data frames have some overlapping data in them for columns 3-10, but I know that the first two columns don't match. How can I iterate through the two dataframes and create a third dataframe that with the schema df1.col1, df1.col2, df2.col1, df2.col2?

In SQL I would do a join using the 3rd through 10th columns as keys, and then the select statement would just return the first two columns for each table - but I don't know how to do this in python.  My 'gut' instinct would be to iterate over the data frame, with something like in pseudo-code:

```
for line1 in df1:
   for line2 in df2:
      if(line1[:3]==line2[:3]):
         write_to_file_1(line1[2:], line2[2:])
      else
         write_to_a_file(nomatch_file1, line1)
         write_to_a_file(nomatch_file2, line2)
```

But I can't get that to work.

Here's some example data

1, 1, TORONTO, OTTAWA, BRAD, DAVIS, JAN, 2020
1, 2, VANCOUVER, KELOWNA, MICHAEL, JENKINS, FEB, 2020

second data frame

43, 45, TORONTO, OTTAWA, BRAD, DAVIS, 2020
44, 46, MONTREAL, HALIFAX, GEORGE, CONSTANZA, MARCH, 2019

In this case, I want to compare TORONTO, OTTAWA, BRAD, DAVIS, JAN, 2020 in first line of the second data frame, so it would return a new tuple

1,1, 43, 45, TORONTO, OTTAWA, BRAD, DAVIS, JAN, 2020

Comment: Please show example data, you don't need to show 10 columns, but 6 would be good. Also define what you mean by 'compare': 'integer equality'? 'floating-point exactness'? 'string equality'? 'substring membership'? 'fuzzy string similarity'? 'list equivalence'? etc.

Comment: Btw, best to call the rows of a dataframe 'row' not 'line'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use df1.merge(df2, on=['city1', 'city2',....])

That works for me, except where the data types are different.